# jwplayer show really small movie on ipad

Tags: jwplayer6

I am using jwplayer to embed responsive videos and I have a few issues:

First, on iPad, the video will always be small. I'm using

```
'width': '100%'` and `'aspectratio': '12:9'`
```

and the video container size is ok but the movie is really small with a lot of black screen around it.  Also, if I fix the width and height, the movie is still very small.

I tried using iframe - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406644-making-jw-player-responsive.  Now the movie size is ok but I can't find an option to add poster.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a tiny video on host and you want to play it as original size this issue happend.
use this below:

```
width: '100%',
aspectratio: "16:9",//Common values are 16:9, 24:10 or 4:3
stretching: "uniform"//stretching (uniform,fill,exactfit,none)
```